# Wake-up freezes and black screen on Macbook (Iris Pro gpu)

Tags: 18.04, macbook-pro

Sometimes, I need to hard power off the Macbook as it refuses to show me any UI when opening the lid or even pressing the Power button. Other times, as I type the login password, the screen freezes and/or wifi disconnects. This does not happen on my other Dell PC which runs the same (latest) version of Ubuntu. What can I do to solve it?

Also to mention that when I log in to the system, freezes and black screens never happen any more, so something is wrong with wake-ups specifically.

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes had wake-up freezes too on my MacBook with Ubuntu 16.04. They were gone after resetting the SMC.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295

However I must add that soon after doing this I upgraded to 18.04, so not sure what really fixed the freezes ;) Give it a try!

Tobi

Comment: Thanks for the comment, let me try that soon. So far I used UKUU to upgrade the kernel which completely axed the system (even old kernel are unbootable now) and now I'm installing a parallel ubuntu from USB in the hope that I can mount in my old home directory. Will be reporting if the problem persists with the new install, and if the SMC reset fixes it.

Comment: I get wake up problems even with the SMC reset, often need to hard reset, other times it flickers like this: https://photos.app.goo.gl/fHQxqcb6hknsRf7X9